# commit (a) sacrilege (what's the differnce with 'a' or without 'a'?)

Tags: articles

> commit (a) sacrilege

Wonder whether there is any difference in 'meaning' or in 'tone'

Is there any rule we should know that 'a' is not needed or omitted?

The only difference is 'a' or without 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

commit sacrilege (uncountable) = commit the crime of sacrilege.

OED

**1.a. The crime or sin of stealing or misappropriating what is consecrated to God's service. In ecclesiastical use, extended to include any kind of outrage on consecrated persons or things, and the violation of any obligation having a sacramental character, or recognized as under the special protection of the Church. *Also, an instance of this offence.***

> 1875   H. E. Manning Internal Mission of Holy Ghost ix. 235   *The very books that are used in the worship of God are Sacred. The man who steals them is guilty of sacrilege.*

commit a sacrilege (countable) = commit an example of a sacrilegious act.

> 1827   R. Southey Hist. Peninsular War II. 239   *In consideration of the **sacrileges** which the enemy committed..they were enlisting the peasantry.*

I'm sure you will recognise commit **robbery** and commit **a robbery**

Comment: Can you find any sources that say it's countable, or that use it in a countable way?

Comment: I am amazed that was necessary - nevertheless, I have edited - see above.

Comment: Don't be sure of my knowing between them.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, *sacrilege* is mostly used in an uncountable sense, without an article.  [This Google Ngrams search shows that the countable use *sacrilege* is at most about 14%.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28a%20sacrilege%2Fsacrilege%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) In your example, it would almost certainly be uncountable, like

> I do not wish to commit sacrilege.

The majority of dictionaries seem to define it as uncountable.

- [Collins dictionary: UNCOUNTABLE NOUN [also a N]:
  Sacrilege is behavior that shows great disrespect for a holy place or object.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sacrilege)
- [Oxford learners dictionary: sacrilege noun /ˈsækrəlɪdʒ/
  [uncountable, singular]](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sacrilege#:%7E:text=noun-,noun,thing%20or%20place%20without%20respect)

Answer (score 0):

"A" sacrilege is one offense. Committing sacrilege could be multiple sins and the tone feels more serious to me. Committing sacrilege is more broad and leaves more to my imagination  as to what this person has done. A sacrilege seems more forgiving and it sounds as though it's out of character for the person. Committing sacrilege sounds like the person is living a life full of sin.